# Yarn watch, Can not get /

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

Im trying to get some server side rendering to work for my react project with yarn, webpack and babel. When I type in yarn watch in the terminal the program compiles correctly and then the localhost window appears, It says "Can not get /". This is because I need a output(I think), but I am unsure as in how to create one correctly.

here below is the code inside my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src" ),
        historyApiFallback: true,
        writeToDisk: true,
    },
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js" ),

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, use:"babel-loader"
                
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["css-loader"]
            
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                use: ["url-loader"]
            },
           
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },

    
    
};
```

The Bundle.js filename in the output was made in the public folder inside the index.html.

```
 <script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Sorry if this made no sense but I dont understand how this does not work correctly.